# Find all combination of values which total equals N (javascript)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am calculating some chemistry for which i need combination of values which total equals N number. I have following array for which each values can't be more than X

Array :
Index |  Max Value
0     |  370
1     |  185
2     |  740
3     |  277.5
4     |  277.5
5     |  1850
6     |  925
7     |  1850

i need a function which will calculate all possible combination of values from each array index which total equals 1850.

Eg.
0 | 77.00
1 | 700.00
2 | 50.00
3 | 300.00
4 | 700.00
5 | 15.00
6 | 7.00
7 | 1.00
which Total = 1850

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return all subsets whose sum is a given value (subset sum problem)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53659151/return-all-subsets-whose-sum-is-a-given-value-subset-sum-problem)

Comment: @aRvi above question is a static array which will be passed, i want any combination of values which does not exceeds max value

Comment: _"...can't be more than X ..."_  - but can be zero or negative?

Comment: @ Tibebes. M  It should be positive, no zero or negative

Answer (score 1):

Here is one approach.

- sort the array in ascending order (to make the distribution a bit fair - since we will be looping for first to end sequentially and pick numbers, the large numbers might shadow the smaller numbers for having a chance)
- prepare a new array for result (initialize with 0)
- for each entry in the sorted array, we will take some random value until (the the total sum is reached) - we are decreasing some counter variable in this example to track that (`pointsLeft`). Add the randomly picked number to the result array at the specified index (the result array index should follow the original array's order - not the sorted one)
- if there is not `pointsLeft`, it means the items in the result array is equal to the desired sum. So we just return the result array.

```js
const testArray = [
  370,
  185,
  740,
  277.5,
  277.5,
  1850,
  925,
  1850,
]

function getRandomInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
}

function getCombination(values, pointsLeft) {
  let sorted = values.map((x, i) => {
    return [x, i]
  }).sort((a, b) => a[0] - b[0]); // sorted from small -> large - keeping the original index

  const result = new Array(values.length).fill(0)

  while (pointsLeft > 0) {
    for (const [_, [value, original_index]] of sorted.entries()) {
      someRandomValueToSubtract = getRandomInt(1, value / 2)
      if (pointsLeft - someRandomValueToSubtract < 0) continue
      pointsLeft -= someRandomValueToSubtract
      result[original_index] += someRandomValueToSubtract
    }
  }

  return result
}

const x = getCombination(testArray, 1850)

console.log("ITEMS:", x)

console.log("SUM:", x.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}, 0))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @ Tibebes. M great solution, instead of assuming some random numbers, can we get all combinations which sum to 1850?

Comment: @NitinMuchhadiya Oh, I think calculating all the combinations with such max-values would be highly memory intensive task (and impossible if floating numbers are considered - infinite possibilities).  I'll update the answer if I find an optimized solution though.

Comment: @NitinMuchhadiya, note that there could be potentially  `1.2304101e+22` amount of checks if we were to check all combinations (assuming only integer values and your input array)

Comment: that would work for me, hope so there will be no memory issue using this

Comment: I meant it's near impossible to retrieve all :)

Comment: @ Tibebes. M Thanks a lot, i have made solution from the random numbers that you posted above.