# efficientely derive what elements of an array have been summed

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an input array, like so:

```
const dels = [ // up to 50 possible
  {no: 491, weight: 1348},
  {no: 492, weight: 694},
  {no: 1054, weight: 4104},
  {no: 1181, weight: 2636},  // *
  {no: 2096, weight: 4084},
  {no: 2201, weight: 4064},
  {no: 2296, weight: 2364},
  {no: 2365, weight: 1670},
  {no: 2632, weight: 4084},
  {no: 2891, weight: 2424},
  {no: 3051, weight: 2414},  // *
];
```

I also have an array of sums, like so:

```
const sums = [5050, 24836]; // up to 4 possible
```

The structure is fixed, but the numbers are unknown (come from an external source).

I know that each number of the `sums` array is the sum of some `weight` members of the other array (each `dels` item counted exactly once).

So this can be assumed:

```
const sumDels = dels.reduce((a,i) => a + i.weight, 0);
const sumSums = sums.reduce((a,i) => a + i, 0);
sumDels === sumSums // is true

sumDels.every(x => x.weight > 0) // is true
```

**What algorithm can *efficiently* give me the possible combinations that lead to the given sums?**

A possible result could look like this:

```
const goodResult = [ // <-- array of possible combinations (theretically, there could be more than one)
  [                  // <-- `dels` array mapped with `sumIdx`
    {no: 491, sumIdx: 1},
    {no: 492, sumIdx: 1},
    {no: 1054, sumIdx: 1},
    {no: 1181, sumIdx: 0},  // *
    {no: 2096, sumIdx: 1},
    {no: 2201, sumIdx: 1},
    {no: 2296, sumIdx: 1},
    {no: 2365, sumIdx: 1},
    {no: 2632, sumIdx: 1},
    {no: 2891, sumIdx: 1},
    {no: 3051, sumIdx: 0},  // *
  ]
];
```

A naive solution would try all permutations but with sums.length==4 and dels.length==50 that's 1267650600228229401496703205376 possible combinations, if I'm not wrong... ;-)

Comment: Looks like [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem)

Comment: [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments, this is known as the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) and I've learnt that usually there is no other way to try all combinations, while bailing out early when a combination is already identified as being wrong.

This led me to [another Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53659385/688869) with a nice recursive implementation.

It handles only one sum, though (my `sums` array could reach up to 4 numbers), but it's a good starting point for the full solution.